# When opening a blend file, it gets stuck at compiling shaders

Tags: materials

It's most likely that my laptop can't handle it, but I've been using Blender for a year or two on my laptop without any problems, but blend file just doesn't load at all.

It's a Destiny 2 model, also I don't know how to put this blend file to this thing.

#### Specs:

i3-1125g4, 8 gigs of RAM and Intel UHD graphics (idk it just says that on task manager)

[image]

Comment: If this is the first time you've entered rendered view in blender, or if you recently installed new drivers, there is a one-time shader precompilation stage that can take SEVERAL minutes to complete depending on your system.  Might be worth it to start it and walk away for some time, see if it eventually continues.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - it's probably the graphics card that is having trouble to cope with a complex shader or fit it into its memory. It seems like there are a lot of different shaders mixed in one material, if they have a lot of textures, it is likely that a laptop with integrated Intel GPU cannot handle it. Try giving it a few minutes or reopening the file making sure you have no other programs running. It seems to me there is really nothing much that can be done about it in a Blender Stack Exchange answer.